# Convert from a SQL table to SAS data?

Tags: dataframe, sas, dataset, proc-sql

I don't know any SAS and I'm modifying and enhancing a pre-exisiting program.

When I create the table stratacomparison, I can view it and all the data it contains in my work library explorer.

When I then try to use the table to make a modified dataset stratacomparison2 I get an error saying 'File work.stratacomparison.**data** does not exist'.

I presume its because I've made a **table**, not a **data**set? Is there a way to convert it from a table to a dataset?

```
PROC SQL; 
    create table stratacomparion
    as SELECT (case when a.cell_no is not null then a.cell_no when b.cell_no
               is not null then b.cell_no when c.cell_no is not null then c.cell_no
               else 999999999999 end),
               a.samp_size, b.cell_no as cell_no2, b.prev_samp_size, b.prev_bign, 
               c.cell_no as cell_no3, c.bign
    FROM neyman_uk_allocation as a 
    FULL OUTER JOIN LASTyearalloc as b
    on a.cell_no = b.cell_no
    FULL OUTER JOIN current_n as c
    on (case when a.cell_no is null then b.cell_no else a.cell_no end) = c.cell_no;
    quit;

data stratacomparison2;
set stratacomparison;
  rename _TEMA001=cell_no;
  label _TEMA001=cell_no;
  if samp_size=. then samp_size=0;
  if samp_size='.' then samp_size=0;
  if bign=. then bign=0;
  if bign='.' then bign=0;
  proportional_sample = 29500*bign/206318;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have a typo.  You created `stratacomparion` but are asking to read from `stratacomparison`.  You left out the last `s` in your first statement.